# Is it possible to just get a "set" using a Flickr's feeds?

Tags: php, javascript, api, feed, flickr

I'm trying to grab photos from a specific "set" on Flickr as opposed to the entire user's photostream. Does anyone know if this is possible using Flickr's feeds (http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/)? It looks like you can only select tags, but I need to grab a set. (tags are not an option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to URLs formatted as follows:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photoset.gne
    ?set=<photoset_id>
    &nsid=<user_id>
```

For example, http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photoset.gne?set=72157622566768892&nsid=8344375@N07

---

The list on the [feeds page linked in the question](http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/) is not an exhaustive list of *all* of the available feeds from Flickr, as hinted at by:

> While feeds are linked to throughout the site, some can be further customised with additional parameters, documented below.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be of any use? I'm not really sure what you mean, but this retrieves images from a specified photoset
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html

Comment: I was trying to use the API calls that don't require any authentication. The link that you posted requires an API key.